# jQuery serialize multiple forms and send as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I have multiple forms on a page where each form will add individual item to the database. There's also an 'Add all' button that'll send all products data.
See basic html below:

```
<button type="submit">All all products</a>

<form>
<input type="hidden" name="Product" value="ProductA" />
<input type="checkbox" name="optionAll" value="Option All" /> Option All 
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Option 1" checked="checked" /> Option 1 
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Option 2" /> Option 2
<button type="submit">Add this product"</button> 
</form>

<form>
<input type="hidden" name="Product" value="ProductB" />
<input type="checkbox" name="optionAll" value="Option All" /> Option All 
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Option 1" checked="checked" /> Option 1 
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Option 2" checked="checked" /> Option 2 
<button type="submit">Add this product"</button> 
</form>
```

I'm trying to post the serialized form data into the following JSON format:

```
products = {
    "ProductA": {
        "option": ["Option 1"] // only 1 checkbox is checked
    },
    "ProductB": {
        "optionAll": "Option All",
        "option": ["Option 1", "Option 2"] // both checkboxes are checked
    }   
}
```

I've been playing around with mapping the serialized data but couldn't get it into the JSON format like above.

```
data = $.map($('form').serializeArray(), function(el, i){
    var json = {};
    ???
    return json;
});
console.log(data)
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I can think of an "easy" jQuery way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = {};  // object to hold final result

$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {

    $('form').each(function() {  // loop start for each form

      var sr = $(this).serializeArray(),
          options = [];

      result[sr[0].value] = {}; // insert Product value and initiate it as object

      $.each(sr, function() {  // loop start for each checkbox

        if(this.name == 'option') {

            options.push(this.value);

        }

      });

      // if all checkbox are checked then insert the property optionAll

      if(options.length == $('input[type="checkbox"][name="option"]',this).length) {

        result[sr[0].value].optionAll = 'Option All';  

      }

      result[sr[0].value].option = options;

   });

   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found a couple things: OptionAll is always passed eventhough it's not checked, and option1 and/or option2 are not being passed eventhough they're checked. Do you see it also?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi codeparadox, how would I modify the code if I need to flatten the JSON like so: products = {
    "sku": "ProductA",
    "option": ["Option 1"] // only 1 checkbox is checked
    },
    "sku" : "ProductB",
    "optionAll": "Option All",
     "option": ["Option 1", "Option 2"] // both checkboxes are checked
    }   
}

Answer (score 0):

To serialize as a JSON string a javascript object, simply use

```
JSON.stringify(myobject)
```

So your work is mainly to make the object :

```
 var products = {
 };

 products['ProductA'] = $('input[name="Products"]').find(':checked').val();
```

and so on...

But you really should change a little your html : you should really avoid to have identically named inputs. Try to give them an id at least.